# MS SQL Insert Trigger Checking for Correct Number Format in Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I
need some code advice,

when printing out offers, our ERP Program generates an ID Number in the Table "Angebot" in the format AYYNNNNN, this mask is set in the administrative settings, but it also has an option to override this number and set a manual one, which causes lots of trouble, as people tend to break the id counter.

I'd like to create a trigger that sends a message when the id number is not in the correct format, so I have to check for that specific column to be correct.

The if statenent would check the following:

```
if (Angebotsnr NOT LIKE 'A'+RIGHT(DATEPART(yy,getdate())+'_____') then RAISEERROR
```

There is already an existing trigger in the database that checks for something else, so I only need to add the second check to ensure that it is right, but where would I put the if statement and how do I check it?

This is the code of the existing trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ANGEBOT_ITrig] ON [dbo].[Angebot] FOR INSERT AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
/* * KEINE EINFÜGUNG BEI FEHLEN EINES PASSENDEN SCHLÜSSELS IN 'ErlGrp' */
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) !=
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ErlGrp, inserted WHERE (ErlGrp.ABTNR = inserted.ABTEILUNG))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ( 'Some error statement',0,0)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

The action would be the same, just with a different error message. 
Can someone point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You could add it to this existing trigger, after END. something like  `if (select Angebotsnr from inserted  NOT LIKE 'A'+RIGHT(DATEPART(yy,getdate())+'_____') BEGIN RAISEERROR ('error') END`  should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle this in the procedure that's doing the insert so it doesn't ever insert and fire off other triggers.

```
create proc myInsertProc (@ID char(8))
as
begin
    --copied from you, but it's missing part of the right function
    if (Angebotsnr NOT LIKE 'A'+RIGHT(DATEPART(yy,getdate())+'_____') 
    begin
        raiserror('You provided a wrongly formatted ID',16,1) with log
        return
    end
    ...continue on with other code
end
```

This will raise the error, and write it to the SQL Server Error Log. You can remove `with log` if you don't want that. The `return` ends the batch. You can also wrap this in a try catch on insert if you'd.

I'd use this in the `IF` block personally.

```
if (Angebotsnr NOT LIKE 'A' + right(convert(varchar,DATEPART(year,getdate())),2) + '%' or len(Angebotsnr) != 8)
```